# version compatibility issues with jasper reports and iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have an existing jrxml files which is formatted like the code below:

```
    <band height="25" isSplitAllowed="true">
            <rectangle radius="0">
                <reportElement key="rectangle-2" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="782" height="25" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#EAECEF"/>
                <graphicElement fill="Solid">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-4" mode="Opaque" x="2" y="2" width="774" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#EAECEF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>....
                    <leftPen lineWidth=
```

When I edit the jrxml file using iReport 3.7.0 or 4.1.1 it will change the format of that xml to the something below:

```
<band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle radius="0">
                <reportElement key="rectangle-2" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="782" height="25" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#EAECEF"/>
                <graphicElement fill="Solid">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-4" mode="Opaque" x="2" y="2" width="774" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#EAECEF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                </box>
```

How can I preserve the format of the jrxml file?

Comment: Did you try to set Compatibility option in iReport?